# About recent site redesign

Tags: support, design

I observed some recent changes on Stack Overflow color pattern and other site design features. It was nice, but I got a little lost.

Is there a place where this changes are listed?
I would like to read them

Comment: Where did you observe this? What aspects of the site’s design or color scheme have changed? I haven’t seen anything different in quite a long time.

Comment: One is that all up and down votes arrows now are colored with each Stack Exchange forum color. Orange for AskUbuntu, blue for Stack Overflow and red  here in meta, for example. 
And the layout of site's question instructions messages has changed too.

Comment: That’s...odd. I don’t see those colors at all. Meta has black highlights on vote arrows, and Stack Overflow has orange highlights. These have always been the colors of those vote arrows, since the very beginning of the sites. Indeed, the Ask Question page has been heavily revamped; that was a long time in coming, and has been discussed many times on Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps you haven't been selected as a premium valued member of the behavioural experiment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no public change log provided by the Stack Exchange developer team.

Second to best is the community curated list of recent changes:

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

Another source of hints and background on feature changes can be found by following the [announcements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/announcements) tag over on Meta Stack Exchange.
The same tag also exists on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/announcement). Alternatively look for [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) tags being added to questions tagged [[bug] or [feature-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bbug%5d%20or%20%5bfeature-request%5d%20%5bstatus-completed%5d%20is%3aq).

If you're into stalking users you could keep an eye on those users with a diamond that are not elected moderators (conveniently labelled as staff) . For example [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis?tab=activity) posted recently on MSO as he was the dev responsible for implementing some of the new features. Their posts often contain valuable information about both implementation details and rationale.

**TL;DR** there is no list of changes, not even a public plan of changes to come. New things are pushed to production at some day and then we all are hit by awe and amazement. Every. Frigging. Time.

Comment: *"and then we all are hit by awe and amazement"* Not always, sometimes we hate the new changes.